# ¿Cómo saber si es la ultima columna de la consulta?

Tags: php

Quiero ir haciendo una iteración, pero en caso de que sea la última columna hacer otra cosa, pero me dice que hay un error

> expected type array

Podría hacer un `array[]=$row`, pero querría saber si hay otra manera de hacerlo más "corto" y directamente:

```
while($row=$preparada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($row === end($preparada)){
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. El `while` en este caso lee todas las filas y el código pasa a lo siguiente. ¿Quieres que NO lea la última fila? Si es así explica por qué o qué quieres lograr con eso.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que en caso de que sea la ultima columna añadir una clase active a un div y mostrarlo, si no es aun el último registro ir mostrando los demás tags, pero que el último tenga esta clase que te digo. Podria hacer un foreach teniendo un array, pero queria saber si habia otra manera directamente haciendolo en el while

Comment: No entiendo... ¿Quieres agregar una clase a la última columna de cada fila o a la última fila entre varias filas?

Comment: En la bd tengo guardadas las rutas de las imagenes e ir mostrandolos normal, pero justamente el último registro que tengo en bd añadirle una clase='active' a la imagen mientras que el resto no tendra esa clase. Es decir a la última de las varias files que ira recuperando.

Answer (score 2):

### Si tu SGBD suporta cursores

No lo he probado, pero esto debería funcionar.

Según la documentación, PDO te permite obtener las filas con un cursor desplazable ([ver **Ejemplo #2** del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)).

Para ello tienes que pasar un parámetro adicional al preparar la consulta.

```
$sql="***SUSTITUYE POR TU CONSULTA***";
#Cambia $pdo por tu objeto de conexión
$preparada = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
/*Los bind si fuera preciso*/
$preparada->execute();
```

Ahora puedes hacer la lectura en dos tiempos:

```
#Obtenemos la última fila
$lastRow = $preparada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);

#Variable para concatenar los datos
$html="";

#Ahora leemos en su orden natural
#Ya en $lastRow sacamos la última fila del fetch, queda el resto de filas
while($row = $preparada->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST) ) {
    #Aquí concatenarás todas las filas que quedan
    #cambia unaColumna por el nombre real, y puedes poner las demás columnas
    $html.=$row['unaColumna'];
}

#Ahora agregamos a $html los datos, que guardamos antes en $lastRow
#cambia unaColumna por el nombre real, y puedes poner las demás columnas

$html.="<div class=\"active\">$lastRow[unaColumna]</div>";

echo $html;
```

Esta sería la forma más natural de hacer lo que quieres. Como dije al principio, no lo he probado, pero debería funcionar sin problema. Si no funciona, la otra alternativa es sacar primero todas las filas en un array y luego hacer una lectura de ese array sacando una referencia del último item del mismo para verificarlo.

---

### Si tu SGBD no soporta cursores

Si tu SGBD no soporta cursores (MySQL y SQLite no lo soportan). Podrías crear un array de todos los datos y luego extraer aparte el último con `array_pop()` o de otro modo.

Veamos un ejemplo. Para simplificar usaremos `fetchAll()`. Si tu consulta espera muchas filas, cambia `fetchAll()` por el `fetch` combinado con lectura en bucle.

```
$allRows=$preparada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
#Extraemos la última fila
$lastRow=array_pop($allRows);

#Variable de concatenación
$html="";
#Ahora leemos todas las filas, menos la última
foreach($allRows as $row) {
    $html.=$row['unaColumna'];
}
#Ahora agregamos la última fila
$html.="<div class=\"active\">$lastRow[unaColumna]</div>";

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Primero**: el resultado del statement se recorre por filas. La idea de verificar la última columna es conceptualmente errónea. Cada iteración del statement tiene su propia última columna.

**Segundo**: el error ocurre porque `end()` espera un array. Tu variable `$preparada` es un [PDOStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), una clase que implementa la interfaz [Transversable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) y por eso puedes recorrerla con un `while` o un `foreach`. Recorrerla no implica saber su contenido completo de antemano.

**Tercero**: La gracia de obtener la respuesta usando `fetch` es que mantienes una sola fila en memoria a la vez.  **Si tienes una certeza razonable de que obtendrás una cantidad manejable de registros**, puedes traer todo de una vez como arreglo:

```
$rows = $preparada->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

y luego hacer lo que tenías planeado:

```
foreach($rows as $rows){
    if($row === end($rows)){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por qué te complicas tanto la vida??

1.- Lo que te recomiendo es que obtengas el **total de registros de tu consulta** y antes del **ciclo while** tengas una variable que se llame **$contador** puedes inicializarla en **1** o **0**

2.- Está variable tienes que incrementarla en el **while** ejemplo: **$contador++**

3.- Por cada **iteración** tendrías que validar si la variable **$contador** es == al **total de registros** significa que has llegado al último registro, entonces haces lo que tengas que hacer con ese registro.

NOTA: Realiza pruebas, imprimiendo la variable **$contador** para que coincida con los registros que tienes. Al igual en tu condición.

Ahora mismo no puedo testear código, pero estoy seguro que si me explique bien podrías solucionar tu problema. Saludos.